# Early Church Fathers' Commentary on Luke 10:16

Tags: catholicism, early-church, church-fathers, gospel-of-luke, bible-commentary

According to Wiki:

> The Church Fathers, Early Church Fathers, Christian Fathers, or Fathers of the Church were ancient and influential Christian theologians and writers who established the intellectual and doctrinal foundations of Christianity. The historical period in which they worked became known as the Patristic Era and spans approximately from the late 1st to mid-8th centuries

Luke 10:16:

> He that heareth you, heareth me; and he that despiseth you, despiseth me; and he that despiseth me, despiseth him that sent me. *(Douay-Rheims)*

Can anyone provide some commentary that (specifically) Church Fathers have made on Luke 10:16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin Martyr, in his First Apology, uses Luke 10:16 as an occasion to criticize the Jews for rejecting Jesus:

> Jesus the Christ, because the Jews knew not what the Father was, and what the Son, in like manner accused them; and Himself said, “No one knoweth the Father, but the Son; nor the Son, but the Father, and they to whom the Son revealeth Him." Now the Word of God is His Son, as we have before said. And He is called Angel and Apostle; for He declares whatever we ought to know, and is sent forth to declare whatever is revealed; as our Lord Himself says, “He that heareth Me, heareth Him that sent Me.”

Irenaeus, in Against Heresies Book III, used it to emphasize the apostolic teaching authority of the bishops.

> the Lord of all gave to His apostles the power of the Gospel, through
> whom also we have known the truth, that is, the doctrine of the Son of
> God; to whom also did the Lord declare: “He that heareth you, heareth
> Me; and he that despiseth you, despiseth Me, and Him that sent Me.

Several other patristic citations of the verse can be found [here](https://www.catholiccrossreference.online/fathers/index.php/Luke%2010:16), which is also the source of the two quotations already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.